# Not able to dynamically style component - TypeScript , Styled-component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a struggle here and I fear I do not understand what is happening.
I am following the documentation of [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics)
and everything seems to be like they described it, but it seems that it is not working on my side.
I am trying to render a Card/div or basically to expand it based on props coming from the parent

```
...
const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)
...
return ( 
   <CardWrapper
        open={open}
        ... />
...
)
```

And here I use my state inside the styled component

```
import { keyframes, css } from '@emotion/react'

import styled from '@emotion/styled/macro'

const expandAnimation = keyframes`
  0% {
    height: 180px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 240px;
  }
`

const unexpandAnimation = keyframes`
  0% {
    height: 240px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 180px;
  }
`

...

export const CardWrapper = styled.div<{open: boolean}>`
  animation: ${(open) => (open 
  ? css`${expandAnimation} 1s ease-in-out ;` 
  : css`${unexpandAnimation} 1s ease-in-out;`)} ;
`
```

Gave it a try also with

```
export const CardWrapper = styled.div<{open: boolean}>`
   ${({ open }) => open && css`
    animation-name: ${expandAnimation }
  `}
`
```

But it seems I am not doing something right. I am pretty new to styled-components, but if someone can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
In order for us to display some animation we need to provide a prop of `ease` and a prop of direction. In my case i use `forwards` and `backawrds`

```
export const CardWrapper = styled.div<{open: boolean}>`
  ${({ open }) => (open
        ? css`animation: ${expandAnimation} 0.7s ease forwards`
        : css`animation: ${unexpandAnimation}1s ease backwards `)
}
`
```